# How to generate custom sales analysis report in sq

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Suppose my table is

```
CREATE TABLE SALESS (id int, product int, salesdate DATETIME, amount float)
INSERT INTO SALESS VALUES 
(1, 1, '2020-10-10', 500),
(1, 1, '2020-11-10', 300),
(1, 1, '2020-12-10', 200),
(1, 2, '2020-10-10', 300),
(1, 2, '2020-11-10', 1000),
(1, 2, '2020-12-10', 200)
```

and my query is

```
select product, year(salesdate) 'year', month(salesdate) 'month', sum(amount)'total maount' from SALESS
group by product, year(salesdate), month(salesdate)
order by product, year(salesdate), month(salesdate)
```

Giving me the result

[image: current result]

What I need as result is like below, how can modify my query to give me this result?

[image: the needed result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select year(salesdate) as year, month(salesdate) as month, 
       sum(case when product = 1 then amount else 0 end) as amount_1,
       sum(case when product = 2 then amount else 0 end) as amount_2
from SALESS
group by year(salesdate), month(salesdate)
order by year(salesdate), month(salesdate);
```

If you really want to add three empty rows for 2021, you can add this before the `order by`:

```
union all
select v.year, null, null
from (values (2021), (2021), (2021)) v(year)
```